# How to click button on dapp/website then confirm transaction in metamask? Then repeat every xx hour

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, metamask

TL;DR I want to automate clicking a button in a dapp then confirm the transaction in Metamask then wait xx time and repeat

So far, I have started working on creating a script using dappeteer and puppeteer which I will share below.

So far with dappeteer I can't get it to switch network to BNB and every time the script runs it has to setup metamask with an account etc which I don't think is ideal!

Can this be done using a chrome extension? I'd prefer this as then it can connect to the existing plugin.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated!

Code

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import dappeteer from '@chainsafe/dappeteer';

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function main() {
    const browser = await dappeteer.launch(puppeteer, { metamaskVersion: 'v10.15.0', defaultViewport: null });
    const metamask = await dappeteer.setupMetamask(browser,{seed: "xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx"});
    await metamask.addNetwork({networkName: "BSC",rpc: "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org",chainId: "56",symbol: "BNB"})

    await metamask.switchNetwork('main')
    await sleep(2000);

    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://app.solarfarm.finance/?ref=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

    await sleep(2000);

    await page.waitForXPath('//div[contains(@class,"chakra-button css-1voh9rj")]');
    var originSelector = await page.$x('//div[contains(@class,"chakra-button css-1voh9rj")]');
    await originSelector[0].click();

    var input = await page.$x('//button[contains(text(),"Connect")]');
    await input[0].click();
    input = await page.waitForSelector("button#connect-METAMASK");
    await input.click();
    await metamask.approve({allAccounts: false});
    page.bringToFront();
    await sleep(2000);

    await metamask.confirmTransaction();
}

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- it looks like you already know how to click on the button in the metamask window. It's the same as any other window, you just have to adjust css for the buttons.
- The chrome extension can't interact with the metamask window, but you can create the transaction in the content page and send it to metamask with the injected window.ethereum. This is a lot to learn though if you haven't used web3 before.
- You can avoid setting up puppeteer each time by using passing --userDataDir=${folder}